# Как правильно прописать вложенные роут?

Tags: laravel

Всем привет. Надо сделать роуты:

```
sitename.ru/articles //получаем все артиклы
sitename.ru/articles/slugArticle //переход на артикл из ./articles
sitename.ru/articles/slugCategory  //выводим артиклы данной категории
sitename.ru/articles/slugCategory/slugArticle  //переход по артиклу данной категории
```

Не могу понять как это прописать в роутах, делаю типа:

```
Route::get('/recipes','RecipesController@index');
Route::get('/recipes/{slugRecipe}','RecipesController@showRecipe');
Route::get('/recipes/{slugTag}', 'TagsController@showTag');
Route::get('/recipes/{slugTag}/{slugRecipe}', 'RecipesController@showTest');
```

Естественно лара ругается на меня за такие кривые роуты... Тыкните пальцем как правильно реализовать.

Comment: Она ругается потому как 2 и 3 Роут ей ни как не различить! по факту ты ей говоришь сделать так '/recipes/{блаблабла}' делай RecipesController@showRecipe'), и '/recipes/{блаблабла}' делай 'TagsController@showTag');

Comment: Тебе нужно либо указать какие то ограничения на правила, что б они отличались, или менять логику, например `Route::get('/recipes/tag/{slugTag}', 'TagsController@showTag')`; `Route::get('/recipes/{slugRecipe}/tag/{slugTag}', 'RecipesController@showTest')`